# Jira send emails from user address

Tags: email, jira

My Jira 4.3.2 instance sends emails from `jira@{domain}.com`. When user, for example Todd, makes a comment on an issue, I would like Jira to send the email from Todd's email address (`todd@{domain}.com`) rather than `jira@{domain}.com`.

Is this possible to configure? This is mainly so that users can hit Reply from their email client and email the person responsible for the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that, but for the sake of limiting your chances of messages getting trapped in spam filters; if the commenter's email address is from a different domain, you may want to set a `Reply-To` header, rather than change `From` to someone else's domain.

Answer (score 2):

From the [JIRA documentation](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+Email+Notifications#ConfiguringEmailNotifications-emailaddress) it looks as if you can only configure one "from" email address per project, not per user.

The advantage of having project specific email addresses is that you can configure email services that will [automatically create or update JIRA issues](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Creating+Issues+and+Comments+from+Email) from emails sent to them.

Comment: One of the ideas of using JIRA is to keep information in JIRA not email. If people replied to a comment by email to that person then the information would be buried back in email not JIRA.

Comment: If you hover on the name of the person who made the change, it should show their JIRA user id, which is probably related to their email address.